# find a path to visit every node in graph not necessarily once

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, hamiltonian-path

I meet a problem but when I google, there are all Hamiltonian Path Problem: How to find a path to visit every node in directed graph(not necessarily once)?

This problem is different from Hamiltonian Path.

For example:

```
1 --> 2 -->  3 ↔ 4 
             ↕ 
             5
```

I have a path $1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow3\rightarrow4\rightarrow3\rightarrow5$ to visit all nodes in this graph, however this graph has no hamiltonian path.

My questions:

> 1. What's the terminology of this problem?
> 2. Is there algorithm or theorem to determine whether a general graph has such path? If a graph has such graph, how to find the detailed
>    path?

Thanks

Comment: Its important to note that not always there is such a path (try to think of an example, after you read D.W's answer). However, in the case there is one, D.W 's algorithm is guaranteed to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably haven't found anything in your searches because this problem is fairly easy to solve, without needing any fancy methods.

If the graph is strongly connected, then it is easy.  Let $s$ be the starting node.  Pick any vertex $v$ you haven't visited yet, and append a path $s \leadsto v$ followed by some path $v \leadsto s$ (both must exist, since the graph is strongly connected).  Repeat, appending to the end of the path, until every vertex has been visited.

If the graph isn't strongly connected, decompose it into a dag of scc's.  Then you can reduce the problem to finding a path through this dag (within a scc, use the algorithm of the first paragraph).  You can find a path to visit every node in a dag iff the dag is itself a path, i.e., it has the structure $v_1 \to v_2 \to \dots \to v_k$, and then it is trivial to write down this path.

This is not a Hamiltonian path, since it may visit the same vertex multiple times.

Comment: You should add that this is not exactly the construction of a Hamiltonian path, since you could visit the same vertex multiple times (though it seems to answer OP's question).

Comment: @Nathaniel, good point.  Done.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your solution. Another question: If every edge has positive weight, I want to find a shortest such path, can I also have an efficient algorithm?

Comment: @maplemaple, no, by reduction from the Hamiltonian path problem (consider the case where all edges have weight 1).  This site isn't intended for interactive use or follow-up questions, so if you'd like a more detailed answer, please try to work out why based on this hint, and if you can't figure it out, ask a new question with the 'Ask Question' button.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to visit vertices more than once, many graph theorists use the term *walk* instead of path, i.e., a *path* is a *walk* where each vertex is visited only once (others use the pair *path* and *simple path* for *walk* and *path*).

The **shortest** walk visiting every vertex may be called a Hamiltonian walk (see [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianWalk.html)), although this notion is not nearly as widely known as Hamilton paths. As a consequence a graph is Hamiltonian if and only if it has a Hamilton walk and this walk has length $n$ (number of vertices) and thus finding a Hamiltonian walk is also hard (as apposed to a walk of arbitrary length).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for, like I was, is the Minimum Spanning Tree. [Here](https://www.adamconrad.dev/blog/minimum-spanning-trees-in-js/) is an article about it.

Comment: The graphs in this question are directed, so "tree" might not be appropriate, but "spanning (closed) walk" is a good suggestion!